# Loading issues to get all filters set in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to set filters stored in my database into the grid on load. This is working right now, but I'm not satisfied with the performance and the way of doing it..

The problem is that i insert my searching parameters into the grid, and afterwards I need to use the triggerToolbar() method.

The catch is when I also wants to set the page and sortorder of the grid. This is making two "reloads", and I think it should be possible to have just have one..

My code:

```
gridDOM.triggerToolbar();

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#Jqgrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { sidx: sortnameFilter, sortorder: sortorderFilter, rowNum: rownumFilter, page: pageFilter }).trigger("reloadGrid")
}, 400);
```

Since triggerToolbar makes an ajax post I need to set the other reload in a timeout. Also something I dont like doing when considering stability.

Anyone got any solution to this?

**Edit:**
The code is running in the loadComplete event.

Answer (score 0):

If `triggerToolbar` makes an ajax request. Call your `reload` in the `success` callback instead of using a `setTimeout`.

```
$.ajax({
  url : '',
  success : function(data){
     //do things
     //call reload
  }
});
```

Comment: I cant set the success function inside of the triggerToolbar method since that is an jqgrid method. Its not custom.